# Flutter and Windows, several problems from 'No implementation..' to 'Failed to remove build', ending with 'Build process failed.'

Tags: windows, flutter

I'm building a WebRTC client with Flutter on Windows.

I have had this problem `MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method startRecordToFile on channel FlutterWebRTC.Method))` traying record a stream.

For the one to solve it, it told me to register Dart Plugins with  `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();`, which did not work.
So I updated the plugins.

```
flutter pub outdated
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

and same results.

So when trying to go back to previous versions it doesn't even let me compile.

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
flutter build windows
```

I also tried `flutter pub cache clean`, and
`flutter clean` gave me this result:

```
PS C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win> flutter clean        
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used
Deleting build...                                                  201ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                               7ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       1ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting ephemeral...                                               21ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         1ms
```

I even restarted the computer.

With that result I can't continue compiling...

```
PS C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win> flutter build windows

 Building with sound null safety 

/C:/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.12/lib/src/native/rtc_video_renderer_impl.dart(11,7): error G76B49859: The non-abstract 
class 'RTCVideoRenderer' is missing implementations for these members: [C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]  
/C:/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.12/lib/src/media_recorder.dart(18,8): error GE5CFE876: The method 'MediaRecorder.startWeb' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'MediaRecorder.startWeb'. [C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.12/lib/src/native/media_recorder_impl.dart(30,8): error GE5CFE876: The method 'MediaRecorderNative.startWeb' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'MediaRecorder.startWeb'. [C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.12/lib/src/native/media_stream_impl.dart(103,15): error G0A556F40: The return type of the method 'MediaStreamNative.clone' is 'MediaStream', which does not match the return type, 'Future<MediaStream>', of the overridden method, 'MediaStream.clone'. [C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Compilaci�n personalizada de "C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win\build\windows\CMakeFiles\7e012dc9275095dffd41e5dc17eebab0\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win\build\windows\CMakeFiles\e7e364d593aab9909a7dd61f45347876\flutter_assemble.rule" terminada con el c�digo 1. [C:\Users\santi\dev\IKUZAIN\fwrtc_win\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...                                         
Build process failed.
```

I have no problem with `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19044.2251], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 3.3.3 on channel stable at C:\sdk\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18a827f393 (8 weeks ago), 2022-09-28 10:03:14 -0700
    • Engine revision 5c984c26eb
    • Dart version 2.18.2
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.1)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.4.33110.190
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19044.2251]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.108
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 107.0.1418.56

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what packages are you using for this project.
May be you should check whether the packages using for the project support Windows platform[image]

Comment: which version of flutter_webrtc package are you using now? @Santi

Comment: Hi @KarolWiśniewski I am using   flutter_webrtc: ^0.9.23
But the error persists. The App is in Windows

Comment: The same error occurs mainly in two situations, one is mentioned above and the other situation is while the imported code isn't correctly injected to your project, in this case can be solved by just stop the project and run again instead of just restarting.